# Upload a picture via ftp with a randomized name C#

Tags: c#, ftp

As the title says, I'm trying to upload a picture from my application but I need to upload many with all different names (eg: PicJ8S23D.png) but I cannot figure it out...

The problem: I made a random string which 'would' create PicJ8S23D.png *but* when I try to upload it I'm unable to find the file (because I'm searching for a file that doesn't exist(because I just randomized the name.))

(I'm taking a picture in .bmp format first thats why I convert it at the bottom.)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Pic.bmp");
    image.Save("Pic"+ RandomString1(5) +".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    UploadImage("ftp://example.com", "uname", "pword", "pic"+ RandomString1(5) +".png");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you append some integer counter to the file name and increment it every time it is used. If you want to use it in multithreaded application, you may need to have a look at Interlocked.Increment()

Comment: How about `Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png"`

Comment: I answered this but I think I didn't understand it so straight (so I deleted my answer). I guess now what you want to do is: on the click event of button1 you upload the same picture multiple times to an FTP folder but with different names. Is that so?

Comment: Well not the same picture, I'm trying to remake something like Gyazo or Printscreen if you've ever heard of that :)

Comment: You post need some clarification. There are tons of question on creating random/unique strings - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+random+string  (so it is unlikely a problem). Please clarify what exactly you are looking for and what causes problem. Make sure to edit post with that information.

Comment: @Tom I noticed you updated your question. Did that change resolved your issue?

Comment: @luchosrock It would work but its giving me an error saying it cant find the file. 'An exception occurred during a WebClient request.' Just to clarify, I'm taking a picture of something when I press the button, making the name random then after trying im trying to upload it, but it cant find the picture because its trying to find another randomized file... I'm really bad at explaining things...

Comment: Maybe try and get the name of the picture or something?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you trying to *load* a file with a random name, or *save* a file with a random name? In your code, it looks to me that you just need to put the output of `RandomString1` into a variable so you can use it again.

Comment: @Nate Varbettini Yes! that sound like a good idea, but I'm a little new to this kind of stuff how would I go about making a variable for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is save the name you're creating in a variable so you can use the same value twice:

`var randomFilename = "pic" + RandomString(5) + ".png";`

The complete solution looks like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var randomFilename = "pic" + RandomString1(5) + ".png";
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Pic.bmp");
    image.Save(randomFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    UploadImage("ftp://example.com", "uname", "pword", randomFilename);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. :)

Comment: @Tom - Just FYI, besides accepting answers, you can also vote up any answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to save an Image with Random Name First and then trying to find the same file then `RandomString1(5)` will give a new string everytime so what you can do is. You should make a variable to store the `RandomString` and then look for the same `RandomString`. Hope code below might help you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string RndString = RandomString1(5);
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Pic.bmp");
    image.Save("Pic" + RndString + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    UploadImage("ftp://example.com", "uname", "pword", "pic" + RndString + ".png");
}
```